# How to determine or provide road type with Geocoding?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, geocoding

Currently I am working on an app which has some sort of navigation through a line drawn over the roads. This line goes through some waypoints on his way from start to finish.

These waypoints are retrieved by using Android's built-in Geocoder `getFromLocationName` and the line is drawn by a JSON request to Google's directions api with driving mode on.

Everything worked fine until I noticed one of my waypoints (which is just streetname + city) is located on a biking road even though most part of that street is a normal driving road. Is there anyway to make sure waypoints only get drawn on a normal driving road?

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate directions, you may specify the transportation mode to use. Make sure driving mode is set. It indicates standard driving directions using the road network.

It's also say in the [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints) that if you specify the waypoints parameter.You can supply one or more locations  in the form of an address, latitude/longitude coordinates, or a place ID.

If you pass an address, the Directions service will geocode the string and convert it to a latitude/longitude coordinate to calculate directions. This coordinate may be different from that returned by the Google Maps Geocoding API, for example a building entrance rather than its center.

So make sure that you use latitude/longitude coordinates is setting waypoints. They will be used unchanged to calculate directions. Ensure that no space exists between the latitude and longitude values.

Comment: I know that. As I stated, the navigation drawing is done using driving mode. However, one of my waypoints I draw to is located on a biking road. This waypoint is set there automatically even though most part of that road is a normal driving road.